# Is there a good way to extract font and color info from a PDF?

Tags: pdf

I'm trying to recreate a couple of charts from the print edition of a publication from a PDF of it. The text is all text, so I'm just looking for font names and a good way to get the colors out of the chart images.

Comment: There are commercial tools for this for use with Adobe Acrobat, but they don't work on Linux. Here you can try e.g. `pdffonts`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try opening it in gedit or your text editor and peeking at the source. There should be declarations of what's being used.

Comment: Now I'm curious about the possibilities to `grep` a binary file, but opening it in vim and searching for "FontName" and "FontFamily" did the trick.